# download image from web and store in sd card. then after retrieve this from sd card and want to show in list view

Tags: android, image, sd-card

This is an image based project.
In this I want to download image from web and store in sd card. Then after I want to retrieve this from sd card and want to show in list view. Also I want to use bitmap method to compress the file. Also cache to fast the process.
Any one can give advice for this project??

Comment: Look at [Android-LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lazy list concept for solving this problem i am sharing the link of this concept with you use it.

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

I hope its helpful to you.